# geoserver use openlayers preview hbase datasource layer prompt java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to create new native thread

Tags: java, hbase, geoserver, geomesa

When I use GeoServer read HBase (GeoMesa) data source, I can use Layer Preview open one layer, but when I open two layers, the second layer can't show, and logs show the error information :

> java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to create new native
>   thread;threadorg.geoserver.platform.ServiceException: Rendering
>   process failed.

I want to know how to resolve this problem and how to set the JVM configuration `-Xms -Xmx`, I don't know which file to set that parameter. please help me, very thanks.

Comment: How are you running GeoServer?  Are you using Jetty, Tomcat, or another Java container?

To increase the memory for GeoServer, you'll need to give a larger -Xmx to the Java container.  The documentation for GeoServer and/or the Java container may help with that.

Comment: very thks,I resolve this question,because the 'max user processes ： 1024’ is too litte,I set this to 10240 in /etc/security/limits.d/90-nproc.conf file, and it's work well.http://blog.csdn.net/wzq294328238/article/details/45538631